# ListView Subtitled delegate, icon size and title word wrapping?

Tags: application-development, qt, qt-creator, qml, qt5

I'm working on an ubuntu mobile app and I have a few questions about customizing a listview.

The listitem may contain an icon, but will have a title and subtitle.

What I'm having trouble with is that the thumbnail is pulled from the internet and I want to limit it's height and width.

Also, the title doesn't wrap if it's too long instead it just truncates and adds "..." at the end.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the documentation for [`ListItem.Base`](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/qml/mobile/qml-ubuntu-components-listitems0-base.html) (from which [`ListItem.Subtitle`](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/qml/mobile/qml-ubuntu-components-listitems0-subtitled.html) inherits):

> icon : variant
>
> The location of the icon to show in the list item (optional), **or an
>   Item that is shown on the left side inside the list item**. The icon
>   will automatically be anchored to the left side of the list item, and
>   if its height is undefined, to the top and bottom of the list item.

You can provide you own image with specific width and height to be used as an icon.

```js
ListView {
    [...]
    delegate: Subtitled {
        id: mySubtitledView
        text: 'Your text'
        subText: 'Your subtext'
        icon: Image {
            source: '<source_uri>'
            width: units.gu(5);
            height: units.gu(5);
        }
        height: units.gu(5)
    }
}
```

Note the `height` parameter set for `Subtitled`, as it will not grow automatically to fit the image's size.

---

As for your second question, I didn't find a "clean" way of formatting the `text`, but you can access directly to children of `Subtitled` and modify there. The main text seems to be the first children of the first children, so this will work:

```js
       Component.onCompleted: {
            // Accessing Subtitled > Item > LabelVisual
            mySubtitledView.children[0].children[0].wrapMode = Text.Wrap
        }
```

This worked for me, but I don't know if it's a robust solution. Maybe others can comment.